# What if we get an answer in user comments?

Tags: support, comments

I asked a question on Stack Overflow, *[How to align a td text to the left of the table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17874504)*. For that question I got answered by Gintas K's comments, but I can't accept that comment as the accepted answer. So I wrote that comment as an answer and accepted it. How do I accept a comment like that as the accepted answer?

Comment: You cannot. What you've done is correct: post your own answer with the complete solution, and then accept it.

Comment: This has been asked/requested/discussed literally hundreds of times here on Meta; the search feature should turn up lots of related questions. Or the "Linked" sidebar, starting with this question: [A method for the OP to accept comments?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/149699)

Comment: You could have left a comment as well to invite the commenter to leave an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't accept a comment **however** you can give it a +1. If you want to accept @Gintas answer ask him to write it as an answer so you can accept it.